# How i can sort a list item by alphabetical order with QSortFilterProxyModel?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qsortfilterproxymodel

Hi i have set the QSortFilterProxyModel property in this mode

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    ....

    ProgramFilterProxyModel programFPModel{};
    programFPModel.setSourceModel(&pm);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("programFPModel", &programFPModel);

   ....

}

ProgramFilterProxyModel::ProgramFilterProxyModel(QObject *parent) :
    QSortFilterProxyModel(parent), m_stringaRicerca(""),
    m_programListCurrIndex(0)
{
    setSortRole(ProgramModel::NameQml);
    setDynamicSortFilter(true);
    sort(0);
    setSortLocaleAware(true);

}
```

....

When i execute my application on Ubuntu the item are correctly sort by alphabetical order because i have set isSortLocaleAware property on true , instead if i try to execute my application on embedded systems with buildroot OS(IMX6 microcontroller) the items aren't sort by alphabetical order.

If i try to print with :

```
qDebug()<< QLocale::system().language()
```

the locale of my buildroot OS the output is "C", instead on ubuntu is italian maybe is this the problem?

How i can sort the items by name and sort by alphabetical order without setSortLocaleAware(true) ?

The order list that i want is the same sort order of a file list for example in ubuntu.

Example:

- a.txt
- A.txt
- à.txt
- b.txt
- B.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set your default locale (as soon as possible in your main())

```
QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::Italian));
```

The above line is just an example. You should set a variable locale, depending on the user preferences, etc.

Or you can overide [the protected method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#lessThan) `bool QSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan()` and compare the items as you wish.
See the [Custom Sort/Filter Model Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-customsortfiltermodel-example.html).